# `go tool pprof` - how to specify source when using go modules?

Tags: go, pprof

I switched to go modules recently and I can't seem to make `pprof` recognize the source files. Maybe someone here knows how to?

I tried using the `-source_path` and `-trim_path` options but I can't figure it out how to make it work.

Interestingly, typing `o` in the interactive mode of `pprof` shows the the `trim_path` option but not the `source_path`.

Just to be sure: `pprof` does work with *local* modules and showing their sources in the stack traces, right?

Answer (score 5):

It does work, I just figured it out.

You need to use both `-trim_path` and `-source_path` together.

`-source_path` should be set to the absolute path to your source code.

`-trim_path` should be set to the path that `go tool pprof` is saying the code should be at.

So if pprof is saying the path does not exist at `/abc/your/code/main.go` then set the trim path to `/abc/your/code/` make sure that the `-source_path` contains the main.go though.